# why cannot find std::pair in netbeans on ubuntu

Tags: c++, std-pair

I have just configured c/c++ in netbeans on ubuntu
and when i try to use std::pair it seems that the compiler cannot find it
that is very strange
the default version of c++ is c++11
that a slice of my code

```
int n, k;
cin >> n>>k;
vector<pair<int,int> > x(n);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to add  <utility> in your program?

Comment: The code you've shown requires `#include <iostream>`, `#include <vector>`, `#include <utility>`, and the [highly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465) `using namespace std;`. Are all of these present in your code?

Comment: I recommend you check e.g. [this `std::pair` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: that's sure that i have written

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

but it seems the i miss #iclude <utility>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the right header files a the beginning of your source files so that the compiler know the different types/objects:

```
#include <iostream> // For std::cin
#include <vector>   // For std::vector
#include <utility>  // For std::pair
```

And use the std namespace by default if you want (before main() typically):

```
using namespace std;
```